# Codeception: record interaction and generate tests from it

Tags: php, generator, record, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to write some acceptance tests with Codeception, but I've noticed that it can be very repetitive. So I'm looking for something that record interaction with a website and generate codeception acceptance test from it.

I've found this one [Codeception TestTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codeception-testtools/jhaegbojocomemkcnmnpmoobbmnkijik), but it's not working weel.
A good one is this one [Katalon Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid), but it doesn't support Codeception.

To summarize, I need a tool that has Katalon's record and Codeception's test generation.
Any ideas or suggestion ?